# Unable to start snmpd

Tags: dpkg

I tried to run `dpkg -r` to remove an installed package but got the following:

```
>sudo dpkg -r my-pckg
(Reading database ... 57461 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing my-pckg ...
No munin plugin provided. Not deconfiguring munin
Deconfiguring snmp entries
Warning: Failed to restart snmpd service. .
Please run sudo service snmpd restart
Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
```

When I tried to restart `snmpd`, I got the following

```
>sudo service snmpd restart  
* Restarting network management services:
```

When I list all the services (`sudo service --status-all`), snmpd is showing as

> [ - ]  snmpd

What is the role of snmpd in dpkg removal?  How can I fix this issue?